# Administrator password does not exist

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to create a new user account but when I click on the "Add or remove user accounts" options in the control panel, the User Account Control dialog box pops up and asks me to type an administrator password but theres no field to enter the password.

Comment: Please show us a screenshot.

Comment: I tried uploading a screen shot but it keeps saying Ill have to have a rating or something so I removed the picture.

Comment: just upload it using imgur, Google drive or another site and paste the link here in the comments

Comment: Ok. Here is the image.     https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5-uiac0Vvf_QXlSU2NZeENPbmM/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0):

This sounds difficult. I don't know how to fix it. Maybe click on "Show Details" next time. If it doesn't work, try logging in to the Admin account. If you don't know how to do that you can still try to use cmd to do the changes to the user accounts.

This tutorial for example shows how to rename a user:
https://www.windows-commandline.com/rename-local-user-account/